# Is there a way to paste multiple things on windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, copy-paste

I was doing some work when I realized that it will be a lot easier if I can copy and paste multiple items from the clipboard.

For example, if I had this in my clipboard:

Oldest

- item 3
- item 2
- item 1

Most recent

Would I be able to do something like this?

Ctrl-V-1 : *Paste item 1*

Ctrl-V-2 : *Paste item 2*

Ctrl-V-3 : *Paste item 3*

If something like this is possible, can you please explain it to me? Thanks.

Comment: Not possible without a 3rd party tool. There's lots of them on the web, Google clipboard manager or something similar.

Comment: [Clipboard manager reviews](http://lifehacker.com/5298615/five-best-clipboard-managers)

Answer (score 0):

**DittoClipboardManager**

I heavily recommend this little-piece of software: [Ditto clipboard manager](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/)

1. This is a clipboard manager that helps you to manage your clipboard
   easily for multi-copy-paste of different types of texts, images,
   files, .... and so on.
2. it enables you to set your own hotkeys for fast-copy&paste also, you
   can share your copies with your friends through the network,
3. it gives you the ability to edit your copies and paste them in
   different ways

Comment: I've removed your signature. It still feels a lot like ad copy though. Rather focusing on features, maybe focus on how it solves his problem specifically, and how its used here.